# Rails 3 Ajax-JQuery: view not updated when destroying an object

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I encounter an issue when I destroy an object in AJAX with Rails 3.2.11.

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-ajax.htm

The controller works fine, but in the view, nothing is done properly. I think my problem is JQuery, but I'm not sure, so where is my problem?

```
//views/tournaments/index.html.haml
%table.table.table-hover.table-bordered
 %thead
  %th Name
  %th Place
  %th Nb players max
  %th
  - if can? :update, @tournaments
   %th
  - if can? :destroy, @tournaments
   %th
 - @tournaments.each do |tournament|
  %tr
   %td= tournament.name
   %td= tournament.place
   %td= tournament.nb_players_max
   %td= link_to 'Show', tournament
   - if can? :update, @tournaments
    %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_tournament_path(tournament)
   - if can? :destroy, @tournaments
    %td= link_to 'Destroy', tournament, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, :class => 'delete', :remote => true
```

My controller tournaments_controller.rb:

```
 def destroy
  @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:id])
  @tournament.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to tournaments_url }
   format.json { head :no_content }
   format.js   { render :layout => false }
  end
 end
```

destroy.js.erb:

```
console.log("hello");
$('.delete').bind('ajax:success', function(){
 console.log("delete!");
 $(this).parent('tr').fadeOut(400, function(){
  $(this).remove();
 });
});
```

The console tells me that the controller works fine (200 OK), Hello is showed in the console but nothing else...

What happened? :-(

EDIT:

I did a test, creating a project exclusively to test this tutorial and it works fine. But not in my project above :(

EDIT for @DickieBoy:
I tried this but didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.delete').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  console.log("delete!");
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function () {
   $(this).remove();
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Are you adding the ajax success event from within a dom ready event?

Comment: Like this?
$(document).bind('ajax:success','.delete',function() {....}

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, too difficult to read here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the solution!**

When you call

```
:remote => true
```

it does the action in the controller and after, the destroy.js.erb.

The document is already ready, and using JQuery, this is very simple. To do this, we only need to do:

```
$('#del-<%= @tournament.id %>').closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function () {
 $(this).remove();
});
```

@tournament.id??? it comes from here, in my view:

```
%td= link_to 'Destroy', tournament, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, :id => "del-#{tournament.id}", :remote => true
```

And all works! ;-)

EDIT:

> You also have the problem of passing the id of the tournament into the javascript so you will have a unique piece of javascript for every tournament that is on the index page. I must have missed something, on 'delete' being logged. What event triggers the current code? – DickieBoy 21 hours ago
>
> > remote: true turns the elements action into an ajax call. So either ajax:success was running or the call wasn't working. – DickieBoy 20 hours ago

It's not a problem to take the tournament ID. Firstly, my view has this element:

```
  %td= link_to 'Destroy', tournament, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, :id => "del-#{tournament.id}", :remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm'
```

When I click on it, this call AJAX (You're right!). But before, it does the action inside my controller:

```
def destroy
  # @tournament is finded in a before_filter (or before_action for those using Rails 4)
  @tournament.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to tournaments_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js
    # thanks to this, I can call my destroy.js.erb
  end
```

Because the destroy action is a success, it calls the destroy.js.erb:

```
$('#del-<%= @tournament.id %>').closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function () {
 $(this).remove();
});
```

> closest works here because of the specification of html tables, you should be using parents, it more accurately describes what is happening. – DickieBoy 20 hours ago

About 'closest', I think this is a better answer than 'parents' in my case. It seems to be faster. Look at here: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquerys-closest-parents/

I hope I understood your questions and answered them correctly :-) I'm open minded to suggestions :-)

PS: I maybe forgot to tell you that I'm using JQuery UJS. Here is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Although it has worked for you, you never found the actual problem, the question states that you didn't see the delete message, but if this is your solution, you must have been. I found the actual problem, see my newly edited question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not totally correct. You're right when you tell about 'parent'. But I changed this in 'closest' in my edit. Moreover, **delete** log doesn't appear in the console, and it was the most important. ajax:success doesn't trigger because I'm using **remote: true** in my view. :-)

Comment: You also have the problem of passing the id of the tournament into the javascript so you will have a unique piece of javascript for every tournament that is on the index page. I must have missed something, on `'delete'` being logged. What event triggers the current code?

Comment: `remote: true` turns the elements action into an ajax call. So either `ajax:success` was running or the call wasn't working.

Comment: `closest` works here because of the specification of html tables, you should  be using `parents`, it more accurately describes what is happening.

Comment: The now edit makes sense :D. I assumed it was in a general js file by the way is was written and not rendered and ran when the controller action is ran. Therefore the actual problem was the point in time the event was being bound, the js would only run after the first element had been destroyed. You now need the ID to find the context as you have lost the original event.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but I assume this constraint :-) Can you vote 'up', I want post questions with photo's and gain more reputation? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the `ajax:success` event is bound to the 'delete' class before any 'delete' classes exist. Therefore:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete').bind('ajax:success', function(){
    console.log("delete!");
    $(this).parent('tr').fadeOut(400, function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Should fix it.

I suggest [further reading on jquery events](http://elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/)

---

Edit:

The problem isn't the loading of the events. It is with the call of `parent`.

From the jQuery docs:

> This method is similar to .parents(), except .parent() only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

so `$(this).parent('tr')` returns an empty array because the parent isn't a `tr`.

Use this:

```
$('.delete').bind('ajax:success', function(){
  console.log("delete!");
  $(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(400, function(){ // this line has changed
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: I did it, but no changes :) This is really weird, the same code works for a little project and not here, perhaps a problem with Haml?

Comment: I changed bind() to on(), but nothing :(